# Generalized Fourier transform of a Schwartz function.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, integral-transforms

Let $f(x) $ be a Schwartz function. Now, define the generalized Fourier transform of $f(x)$ as follows.

$$  
F(\alpha):= \int f(x)\, e^{i\alpha \psi(x)}\,\mathrm dx
$$

Where $\psi$ is continuously differentiable, but $\psi$ is not constant over any subinterval of $\mathbb{R}$.

I am wondering if $F(\alpha)$ is also a Schwartz function.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Try a change of variable $y=\psi(x)$ to see which kind of conditions are needed

Comment: Ok I'll have a go at it. Thank you.